# How can I draw a rectangle inside a panel in C#?

Tags: c#, paint

I want to draw a rectangle and I want to give position it with respect to the panel bottom.

```
    public void populateTable(int x, int y)
    {
        using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
        {
            Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            g.FillRectangle(b, x, y, 100, 40);
        }

    }
```

When I execute the code above, the rectangle is created successfully. But it's positioned with respect to form, not the panel. If I put x=10, y=10, then it's shown in the upper left corner of the form. But I want to show it in the bottom where I put a panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.CreateGraphics()` creates a Graphics object for `this`, which is the enclosing class - the form in this case.

You should try `panel1.CreateGraphics()` instead.

However, I would recommend not using `CreateGraphics` at all. It's better to handle `OnPaint`, so that your graphics gets redrawn when the form is redrawn (minimized then maximized, etc).

Comment: thanks @Blorgbeard it's working. If i use OnPaint method, can I overide it using the same code above?

Comment: @Ravindu Yes, in handling the `Paint` event, you would use the same code you have above, except you won't need to create a `Graphics` object yourself. You're passed on as part of the event arguments. Access it with `e.Graphics`. And, regardless of which approach you use, **you need to dispose `b`**, the Brush object. Wrap it in a `using` block the same as you did with the Graphics object.